How do I create a scrolling screen and randomly appearing pipes for a game of flappy bird on the rasperry pi pico H?
I know how to create a scrolling screen that displays text but creating randomly placed pipes and combining these is proving to be very difficult, any advice will be greatly appreciated!
I have tried drawing pipes out pixel by pixel however i dont understand how to combine the scrolling screen aspect and randomly placed pipes. I have tried using WIDTH, HEIGHT = display.get_bounds() and using HEIGHT and WIDTH combined with rand, to ceate this feature with no success.
